# Where is the paradox in the double-slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

I'm aware of the fact that Feynman said something along the lines of *"If you don't think QM is weird then you don't understand QM"*. So I'm pretty sure he is right and I am wrong :)

Still, when I think of the double-slit experiment I see no paradox.

When a particle (e.g. a photon) is allowed to behave and "be" freely then it behaves a certain way (wave-like behaviour).

But when we try to detect it, then we obviously need to interfere with it in order to detect it and since we interfere with it, we "interrupt" its "normal" behaviour/"path" so it behaves in a different way in that instance (particle-like behaviour).

But same goes for anything being "detected" even in the macroscopic world.

So why is this considered weird or a paradox?

If I naively and crudely extrapolate this experiment to the non-quantum world and think of a football being randomly thrown inside a room bouncing all around like crazy, and then I try to "detect" it by grabbing the ball, well in that instance it makes perfect sense that the behaviour of the ball all of a sudden changes into a very precise location in space.

I understand that this is far-fetched analogy but I hope it illustrates *my* point about "detection"

By nature and definition, detection will necessarily force the thing being detected to be in a certain place no ?

And if we decide to *not* detect/observe such a particle, but rather allow it to *be* freely within itself without interacting with *anything* else other than itself, how can we possibly expect it to be at any particular place in time since being in any particular place in time requires having a reason to be in that particular place in time which requires interacting with something that would cause it to be in that particular place in time but since it is not interacting with anything else other than itself why would it be in that particular place X rather than that other place Y since nothing is causing it to be anywhere at any time ?

Comment: What if you go to catch the football and when you do that you mysteriously find  that you're always at centre court or at the foul line .... never in between!

Comment: I think the paradox is that at the time it was thought that a photon was _either_ a particle or a wave; and which it was had been a long running debate. The "obvious" understanding that you have already accept the dual nature of light.

Comment: That Feynman quote annoys me because it is more than fifty years old.  I think that we understand much more about quantum mechanics than we did fifty years ago.

Comment: Another Feynman quote: "A paradox is a situation which gives one answer when analyzed one way, and a different answer when analyzed another way, so that we are left in somewhat of a quandary as to actually what should happen. Of course, in physics there are never any real paradoxes because there is only one correct answer; at least we believe that nature will act in only one way (and that is the right way, naturally). So in physics a paradox is only a confusion in our own understanding." https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_17.html

Comment: @rob Feynman's quote doesn't say that the weirdness comes from a lack of understanding.  It says the exact opposite.  Are you saying something has changed about that in 50 years?

Answer (score 16):

The reason it is "*paradoxical*" (probably *strange*, *weird*, would be better words as there is no paradox within the laws of quantum mechanics) is the following:

1. The interference pattern in the two slits experiment can be simply understood with (classical) wave-like interpretation of light. However when we dim the light sufficiently we start to see individuals *spots* on the screen. As if light was actually made of particle (that we call photons).
2. However the distribution of the spots on the screen is *as if every photon interfered with itself*.

The first observation sort of forces us to have a particle-like interpretation of light (as opposed to wave-like). The paradox arises because such particles actually behave like waves.

To be even more clear, the paradox arises because we try to interpret photons as classical particles (i.e. pretty much like billiard balls). Quantum particles indeed behave (also) like waves and the paradox is resolved.

A toy model made by Ahronov et al. of the double slit experiment is described in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/450606/1619).

Comment: Yes, to be fair, the thing that I forgot about this experiment which is the only thing that still baffles me is the fact that if you allow individual photos to go through, one by one, even at very large intervals in between, in the end you will see a wave interference pattern which is truly weird. And I believe there is no answer given to this yet? Except for attempts like the pilot-wave theory? Thank you all for your answers by the way.

Comment: Yes there is. The quantum mechanical formalism perfectly explains the experiment. The pilot-wave theory is simply a weird way to interpret the quantum mechanical results with a classical eye.

Comment: PS Just to be clear,  I didn't mean to dismiss pilot-wave theory. I think it's a valid approach to try to salvage some concepts we have a very hard time to let go. On the other hand pilot wave theory than needs to give up something else so we may as well stick with the standard QM. But it's good that people keep investigating these questions.

Comment: The weirdness becomes more obvious when you use something more familiarly thought of as a particle, like electrons.

Comment: A paradox is simply a failure or limitation in our understanding of something

Comment: @ScarlainStimolon - it's not just photons; the same thing happens if you do it with individual electrons, one at a time. This shows that our mental model where we think of electrons as of tiny balls (or "particles") whizzing around is not really correct - the question that arises is how does each electron "know" which parts of the screen to hit more (or less) often (for a pattern to form) if it's not interacting with the other electrons. Turns out, there's a wavelike aspect to particles that allows for wave phenomena (like interference) to manifest with individual electrons.

Comment: Funny things, paradoxes. There's a certain misunderstanding of the concept of "paradox" in this answer and its comments. A paradox is a very particular kind of statement, one asserting the truth of two "seemingly" contradictory substatements, *even if one does not believe that there is actually a contradiction*. The challenge is to explain the paradox. I'm sure you can throw out multiple paradoxes in an elementary quantum mechanics  course. You could immediately explain them, or let the students ponder them. I'm sure you won't run out of them in your course.

Comment: And perhaps there's still an unexplained paradox popping up here and there in quantum mechanics, like whack-a-mole.

Comment: Why doesn't the central section of the double-slit divide the particle?

Comment: @Wookie I think the particle seems to have wave-like properties that allow it to flow through both holes and interfere with itself. A bit like a water wave front going through two gaps in a barrier and forming an interference pattern on the other side.

Answer (score 7):

Of course there is a certain logic to it all, that is quantum physics, however, it is as Feynmann said, a bit strange.

For example, even though we should expect that things should behave differently when they are interacted with, we do not expect that wildly strange things should happen. In the slit experiment, interacting with the photon creates a particle like behavior in the slits, i.e. no interference. However, imagine if you do the experiment with ordinary water waves in a ripple tank. No amount of interacting with the water waves ever causes the water waves to cease exhibiting interference as in the case with the photon. So how can the photon behave like a wave when you leave it be? This is just strange! The paradox is that there is nothing in sensory experience or in classical physics that prepares one for the phenomenon of wave particle duality.

Comment: Perhaps part of the paradox was that the new ideas were indeed a bit, ehh.. unexpected. But a large part was also the "objective collapse" belief that was at that time still popular (it was definitely at the heart of the Einstein-Bohr discussions).

Comment: @JosBergervoet Yes, it is not a true paradox as much as it is simply strange and unfamiliar; "unexpected".

Comment: What if the water in the tank wasn't enough to form waves? Droplets on a window in the rain behave much more like "particles". Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is light really all that special in its duality?

Comment: @Kevin My example emphasizes the difference between waves as a *classical* phenomenon and quantum mechanical waves. For example when dealing with quanta small numbers of them (not enough water in the tank) still exhibit the interference phenomenon, something we wouldn't see in a ripple tank with just a few drops. So, quanta, it seems exhibit a wave-particle duality that goes beyond everyday experience.

Comment: Water waves passing through a double slit get divided. Why doesn't this happen to photons?

Comment: @Wookie Because water waves are not photons. The analogy between classical wave phenomena and quantum mechanical waves simply serves as a way to emphasize that there is nothing in our everyday experience like quantum mechanics. There is no classical standard of comparison, which is what Feynman means when he states that nobody understands quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement "being in any particular place in time requires having a reason to be in that particular place" is not easy to prove, I'm afraid... But perhaps you mean that there must be a deterministic behavior, so being in a place must follow from the initial situation that existed in the past.

This of course was not always clear. Many people believed QM had inherently probabilistic behavior (although it was not present in the mathematical description, so they stated "QM is incomplete" and believed we would find a way to include it in the math). The attempts have failed and most people now have given up on that (after a century) and believe that QM is deterministic and probabilities are only emergent, just like it has always been in classical physics.

Classically, probabilities emerge from amplified small differences by the "butterfly effect". No finite amount of precision can ever allow us to predict the future in such a situation. In QM, probabilities emerge by entanglement and decoherence which leads to branching into pointer states (in the many worlds view the existence of these branches just is accepted, in the older interpretations people thought that only the branch that we observe remains, while the others stop to exist).

The "weirdness" that Feynman and others felt is that in the branches of the QM state the worlds have differences in a lot of places. Exactly that is what keeps things consistent, actually, but having many worlds is still a bit weird if you aren't used to it (although Newton would probably have liked the idea, given his fondness of occult matters! And a "classical multiverse" can perfectly be described by his laws, of course.)

The "paradox" that people felt was related to their insisting that all branches except one would stop to exist, leading to:

1. When exactly does this "collapse" happen? Only in a "measurement?"
2. What does an interaction have to do in order **not** to be a measurement?
3. If at any time some "measurement" takes place somewhere, then QM never works normally, but cotinuously collapses!
4. If it does happen, does it happen in all of space at once, violating the speed of light?!
5. etc.

Thinking about these problems, most people could see that the whole "collapse" hypothesis was more pseudo-science than something else. They also couldn't simply conclude that Everett's "many worlds" view was the correct answer, because the whole decoherence idea was not yet worked out at that time (Feynman's time, I mean... a time long before people like Wojciech Zurek and David Deutsch and others made it more clear).

Comment: I know little about "many worlds"; I need to look into it. As far as I know it is an alternative to non-locality. As far as I know no interpretation has been totally successful at removing the quantum weirdness, which is why I just generally stick with the old Copenhagen approach. It is simple and seems to work just about as well as the rest.

Comment: You are mistaken, Weinberg[1] stated it most clearly: "Bohr’s version of quantum mechanics was deeply flawed, but not for the reason Einstein thought," and Weinberg explains where Bohr failed (namely in failing to describe how the quantum mechanical state actually behaves in time during a measurement, there he only offers hand waving and falling back to classical physics). $$ $$ 
[1] From: Steven Weinberg, "Einstein's mistakes", Physics Today 58 (11), 31–35 (2005).

Comment: Thanks for the reference I will surely look into it!

Comment: I would say that the "collapse" has nothing to do with "measurement". I would say that the "collapse" happens when there is "interaction". "Measurement" just *happens* to be *one* form of "interaction". But I would also say that I have not studied Physics nor Math. I've studied Philosophy so you can now shame me. :)

Comment: Yes, since "measurement" was never clearly defined, your solution of allowing any interaction to be called a measurement is the only fair way out, but that reduces QM to nothing. QM was called "incomplete" because what happens during a measurement had still to be added (but that extension was never achieved satisfactorily). So if any interaction is a measurement, then unaltered QM never serves any purpose. And altering it was no success. So nothing remains! Unless we just accept that collapse does not happen and unaltered QM describes everything, measurements as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Delayed-choice experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser) are pretty weird. You can set up an apparatus so that after the photon has hit the screen, you can decide whether or not to determine which slit it went through. If *after the photon has hit the screen* you decide to check which slot it went through, it will turn out to have behaved like a particle. If you decide not to, and instead erase the information, the photon will turn out to have behaved like a wave. Even though you didn’t decide whether or not to check which slit it went through until *after* it had hit the screen.

Comment: Just to be clear: Delayed choice versions of the double slit utilize entangled photon pairs (i.e. 2 streams). The pairs are detected in coincidence, and it is the pairs that show interference - not either stream of photons alone.  The stream of photons that hits the screen just shows a big blob, no interference is apparent.

Answer (score 0):

It is an experimental fact that obtaining "which-path" information for a photon (for example) has *nothing* to do with being "disturbed".  Yes, most experiments block off one of the two slits.  And for electrons, light is often shined on them to produce which-path information.  But that is unnecessary.  See the following, where the Double Slit experiment is performed one photon at a time:

[Young's double-slit experiment with single photons and quantum eraser](https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf)

See particularly Figures 8 and 9.  In both, there are polarizers over each slit. So there is no difference in whether there is more or less in the path.

- In Fig. 8, the polarizers are parallel; there is NO which-path
  information available and there IS interference.
- In Fig. 9, the polarizers are perpendicular; there IS which-path
  information available and there is NO interference.  This is because
  perpendicularly oriented polarizers in principle provide which-path
  information (even if no one collects it).

And in Fig. 10, another polarizer is added to serves as the "quantum eraser".  Erasers are entirely different subject, and you can read about it in the paper.  But the point is that the "which-path" information can actually be eliminated, in which case the interference is restored.

Comment: It seems to me that blocking off one of the slits would destroy the whole experiment, why would anyone ever expect anything odd to happen if there is only one possible path?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus The usual presentation of a double slit experiment is the comparison of the "wave" interference (through both slits, without a marker to identify path) to the sum (superimposed pattern) of the left-only slit (right blocked) and the right-only slit (left blocked). The left-only and right-only patterns are sometimes called the "particle" presentations, but you should not take the wave vs. particle nomenclature too literally. Classically, you would expect there to be NO difference. Of course the quantum world demonstrates there IS a difference because of self-interference.

Comment: How can a photon pass through two slits without being divided?

Answer (score -4):

To deduce the interference of wave-like particles from a wave-like intensity distribution behind a double slit, was based on a comparison with water waves.
However, there are differences between the behaviour of water waves and EM radiation. For example, two coherent electromagnetic waves travelling in opposite directions pass each other unaffected and do not lead to destructive interference, as is the case with water waves.
Furthermore, in the case of a water wave, there is a change in both the crests and troughs of the wave. In the fringe patterns of the slit experiments, on the other hand, the radiation is deflected. There is no destructive interference in the dark area of the fringe pattern; instead, the radiation is focussed on the light areas. It could also be described as a deflection of the radiation at edges and this angular deflection has a periodic character. It is as if phononic interference between the edge material and the radiation generates resonance patterns.

> When a particle (e.g. a photon) is allowed to behave and "be" freely then it behaves a certain way (wave-like behaviour).

You cite the argument correctly. But the argument itself is wrong. An intensity distribution is only created by influencing the radiation at edges. To infer the wave character of the unaffected radiation from this interaction is pure interpretation (since the process is not observable).

> think of a football being randomly thrown inside a room bouncing all around like crazy, and then I try to "detect" it by grabbing the ball, well in that instance it makes perfect sense that the behaviour of the ball all of a sudden changes into a very precise location in space.

The difference is that you can follow the behavior of the ball - even without catching it. You do not influence the trajectory of the ball through your visual observation. However, you don't have this option with EM radiation or photons or electrons. And everything that happens unobservably is always an interpretation in its explanation. If the hypothetical phononic interference between the edge (the surface electrons of the edge) and the EM radiation were a useful explanation, many a discussion group could turn their creativity to more useful topics. :-)