# What is the interpretation of a non-diagonal density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

Suppose an ensemble of a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particle in the $S_z$ basis is described by a diagonal density operator $$\rho=w_{11}|+\rangle\langle+|+w_{22}|-\rangle\langle-|$$ where $w_{ii}$ are real and non-negative. In this ensemble, measurements of $S_z$ will give the value $S_z=+\frac{1}{2}$ with a probability $w_{11}$ and the value $S_z=+\frac{1}{2}$ with a probability $w_{22}$, and $w_{22}=1-w_{11}$.

What is the interpretation of the coefficients $w_{ij}$ of a nondiagonal density matrix of the form $$\rho=w_{11}|+\rangle\langle+|+w_{22}|-\rangle\langle-|+w_{12}|+\rangle\langle-|+w^*_{12}|-\rangle\langle+|$$ where $w_{ij}$ for $i\neq j$ can in general be complex?

Comment: It is always possible to find a basis in which the density matrix is diagonalized. So, being diagonal or non-diagonal doesn't really convey any useful interpretation. However, the eigenvalues do tell us about a state being pure or mixed (or pure or entangled).

Comment: @abhijit975 Through the eigenvalues or through the condition  $\rho^2=\rho$ tell us whether we deal with a pure state? And please also explain what will I get if I measure $S_z$ in the first ensemble and in the second ensemble.

Comment: Page 4&5 of this pdf may be helpful. http://wwwphy.princeton.edu/~verlinde/PHY305/density2.pdf

Comment: To find what does a measurement of $S_z$ gives, find the trace of the matrix $\rho S_z$. This is the expectation value of the measurement of $S_z$

Comment: $S_z$ measurements on the first ensemble will produce $S_z=+1/2$ half the time and $S_z=-1/2$ half the time. For the second ensemble, what fraction of times shall I get  $S_z=+1/2$ and $S_z=-1/2$?

Comment: @abhijit975  "It is always possible to find a basis in which the density matrix is diagonalized " would mean that you are in the  classical interpretation. For a quantum mechanical system the nondiagonal elements give the quantum mechanical probabilites by those $ρ_{ij}$

Comment: @annav the diagonalization has nothing to do with classical or quantum mechanics per se. It is a theorem from linear algebra that any Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable. But what really matters is the measurement. Is the basis of the density matrix the same as the basis of the operator you are measuring? The nondiagonal terms are only important when you are taking the apparatus and the spin as a composite system. This article is insightful for this discussion: http://vvkuz.ru/books/zurek.pdf

Comment: You lose information of the composite system if you drop the offdiagonal terms.

Comment: @abhijit975  I am not familiar with quatum information. What I remember  is that given a matrix with off diagonal elements non zero, I can tell that the nonzero ij elements still have the quantum mechanical phases which show they are a quantum mechanical system whereas the zero elements have turned into the decoherent classical regime by losing the  phase between the wavefunctions. .. For physics models I do not think it makes sense to say you can always diagonalize, that is a mathematical statement.  A specific description of a specific  system has to describe the system.

Comment: @abhijit975 the off-diagonal elements are coherences and - while they are basis dependent - they nonetheless do have a physical interpretation, particularly because *decoherence* affects these terms.

Comment: related to: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317126/off-diagonal-elements-of-density-matrix-measurement-of-coherence?rq=1

Comment: @annav You are making the common mistake of [conflating the Schmidt basis and the pointer basis](http://blog.jessriedel.com/2014/08/26/how-to-think-about-quantum-mechanics-part-3-the-pointer-and-schmidt-bases/). As anhijit875 says, any state can be diagonalized into a Schmidt basis at any time. But when people talk about decoherence and off-diagonal elements going to zero, they're referring to the pointer basis instead, which is the equlibrium end state of the Schmidt basis after the system decoheres. This is a very subtle point.

Comment: @tparker then in what system is the formulation where parts of the density matrix are shown with submatrices, and som diagonal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is implicit in the general principles, so I'll review the general principles first.

The observable for any component of the particle's spin can be written $\hat u\cdot\vec S$ where $\hat u$ is a unit vector and $\vec S=(S_x,S_y,S_z)$. For any unit vector $\hat u$, this observable has eigenvalues $\pm 1/2$, so we can always write this observable as
$$
 \hat u\cdot\vec S = \frac{1}{2}P + \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)(1-P)
\tag{1}
$$
where $P$ is the projection operator onto this observable's spin $+1/2$ subspace  and $1-P$ is the projection operator onto its spin $-1/2$ subspace. When the observable $\hat u\cdot\vec S$ is measured, the probabilities of the possible outcomes are
\begin{align}
 \text{probability}\Big(\hat u\cdot\vec S \to +1/2\Big) 
  &= \text{trace}(P\rho )
\\
 \text{probability}\Big(\hat u\cdot\vec S \to -1/2\Big) 
  &= \text{trace}\big((1-P)\rho \big),
\tag{2}
\end{align}
where the left-hand sides use a notation that is hopefully clear. Equations (1)-(2) are basis-independent.

The OP uses a basis that diagonalizes $S_z$. Equations (2) imply that if we measure $S_z$, then the probabilities of the outcomes $+1/2$ and $-1/2$ are $w_{11}$ and $w_{22}$, respectively. The same equations imply that if we measure $S_x$ or $S_y$, then the probabilities of both outcomes depend on *all* of the components of $\rho$, including the complex off-diagonal component $w_{12}$.

> What is the interpretation of the coefficients $w_{ij}$ of a nondiagonal density matrix of the form [shown in the OP] where $w_{ij}$ for $i\neq j$ can in general be complex?

One way to answer this is that the probabilities (2) generally depend on $w_{12}$. The *only* exception is when $\hat u=(1,0,0)$ so that $\hat u\cdot\vec S=S_z$.

If a more specific "physical" interpretation of $w_{12}$ by itself is really desired, here's one example of such an interpretation:
\begin{align}
 2w_{12} 
 &=
 \text{probability}\Big(S_x \to +1/2\Big) 
\\
 &-
 \text{probability}\Big(S_x \to -1/2\Big) 
\\
 &+ i\,
 \text{probability}\Big(S_y \to +1/2\Big)
\\
 &- i\,
 \text{probability}\Big(S_y \to -1/2\Big).
\tag{3}
\end{align}
To check this, use the fact that (in one convention) the matrices
$$
 \frac{1}{2}
 \left(\begin{matrix} 
  1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
 \end{matrix}\right)
\hskip2cm
 \frac{1}{2}
 \left(\begin{matrix} 
  1 & i \\ -i & 1
 \end{matrix}\right)
\tag{4}
$$
project onto the $+1/2$ eigenspaces of $S_x$ and $S_y$, respectively, together with
$$
 \rho = 
 \left(\begin{matrix} 
  w_{11} & w_{12} \\ w^*_{12} & w_{22}
 \end{matrix}\right).
\tag{5}
$$
The interpretation (3) looks unnatural because attempting to interpret specific components in a specific basis is technically *always* unnatural. The important message is that any valid physical interpretation must follow from equation (2). The physical content of those equations is basis-independent, just like the physical content of general relativity is coordinate-independent.

---

A comment below the question asked about a relationship between eigenvalues and purity, so I'll address that, too. The state is pure if and only if $\rho^2=\rho$, which is equivalent to the condition that $\rho$ have one eigenvalue equal to $1$ and another equal to $0$ (because the trace of $\rho$ must be $1$). The eigenvalues of $\rho$ depend on all of its components, not just on the diagonal ones, so the purity/impurity of the state also depends on all of its components.