# How do I interpret the elements of a density matrix, and in particular the coherence terms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

I know that [density matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Pure_and_mixed_states) are one way to describe a quantum system. We can write the density matrix of a system as:

$$ \rho = \sum_{\alpha} p_\alpha |\psi_\alpha\rangle\langle \psi_\alpha |$$

I'm a little lost on how to interpret this. I'm consider the following example where I have $| \psi \rangle = c_0 |0 \rangle + c_1 |1  \rangle$.

In this case, my density matrix can be written as :

$$\rho = |\psi \rangle \langle \psi |$$
I interpret this as: this is a pure state (since I can write it as a single outer product) and, in this basis, the population in the state $|\psi\rangle$ is 1.

However, if I now expand this out, I get:

$$ \rho = |c_0|^2 |0 \rangle\langle 0 | + |c_1|^2 |1 \rangle\langle 1 | + c_0 c_1^* |0 \rangle\langle 1 | + c_1 c_0^* |1 \rangle\langle 0 |$$

In this case, I interpret the diagonal elements to be the populations of the $| 0 \rangle$ and $| 1 \rangle$ state, but the rest, I'm not entirely sure.

**My main question: How do I interpret a density matrix?** What do the "coherences" on the off diagonal tell me about my system? Can I interpret this as some sort of mixture that, in this basis, tells me I have some of my system in the $|0 \rangle$ state and some in the $| 1 \rangle$ state?

Comment: Similar question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15792/what-do-the-off-diagonal-elements-of-a-density-matrix-physically-represent

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317126/58382

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have off-diagonal components because you are writing your density matrix in the basis of $|0 \rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$. Note that there exists some change-of-basis matrix $U$ such that $U \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} |c_0|^2 & c_0c_1^{\ast} \\ c_0^{\ast} c_{1} & |c_{1}|^2 \end{smallmatrix} \right] U^{\dagger} = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$.

Purity of your density matrix is a basis-independent statement. The easiest way to check for purity is to calculate $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^2]$, which in your case is equal to $1$ (and so means your state is pure).

The fact that you have off-diagonals in the $\{|0\rangle, | 1 \rangle \}$ isn't really that significant. It just means that $|\psi\rangle$ is a superposition of these basis elements.

Comment: So is there no physical meaning to what a coherence is? (the off diagonal terms in a certain basis). If I coupled my system to a bath and the coherences in the |0> |1> basis go to 0, does this mean my system will now be in a statistical mixture of |0><0| and |1><1|?

Comment: Coherences take on physical meaning in the same way that the basis takes on physical meaning. Your system-bath coupling singles out the $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ basis as remaining stable against decoherence, so the coherences tell you what information from the density matrix will be lost. Indeed, the system would become a statistical mixture of $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $|1\rangle\langle 1|$. More physical meaning could come from an energy difference between $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$; then the relative phase of $c_0$ and $c_1$ will evolve with time leading to measurable interference effects.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, representing the state as a matrix you are making a choice of basis. In that basis/representation, the diagonal elements tell you the probability of finding the state in each possible outcome, when measuring it in that basis.

The off-diagonal elements, generally referred to as *coherences*, tell you about the probabilities of finding different outcomes when measuring in different measurement bases.

For example, for qubit density matrix has the form $\rho=\begin{pmatrix}p_1&c\\\bar c&p_2\end{pmatrix}$, where $p_1,p_2$ are the probabilities of observing first and second outcome in the "computational basis", while the coherence term $c\in\mathbb C$ tells you how the state looks like in different measurement bases.
More specifically, it tells you that $\langle \sigma_x\rangle = 2\Re(c)$ and $\langle \sigma_y\rangle=2\Im(c)$, where $\sigma_x,\sigma_y$ are the standard Pauli matrices. These numbers can be reduced to probabilities of the possible outcomes in the measurement bases defined by the eigenvectors of these two matrices.